# CSS Animation for transform does not work properly when using an initial keyframe with matrix3d value

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I need to execute an animation on a div for properties `scaleZ()` and `translateZ()` using CSS Animations.

The following code works fine when initial and last keyframes values in the animation for `transform` property are in a similar "format":

- 0% is `transform: rotateY(-179deg) scaleZ(2) translateZ(200px);`
- 100% is `transform: rotateY(179deg) scaleZ(2) translateZ(200px);`

```js
        console.clear();
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            let content1 = document.querySelector('#content1');
            var computedTransform = window.getComputedStyle(content1).transform;
            console.log(computedTransform);

        });
```

```css
        @-webkit-keyframes animation {
            0% {
                /*works*/
                -webkit-transform: rotateY(-179deg) scaleZ(2) translateZ(200px);
                        transform: rotateY(-179deg) scaleZ(2) translateZ(200px);
                /*issue*/
                /*transform: matrix3d(-0.999848, 0, 0.0174524, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -0.0349048, 0, -1.9997, 0, -6.98096, 0, -399.939, 1);*/
            }


            100% {
                -webkit-transform: rotateY(179deg) scaleZ(2) translateZ(200px);
                        transform: rotateY(179deg) scaleZ(2) translateZ(200px);
            }
        }

        @keyframes animation {
            0% {
                /*works*/
                -webkit-transform: rotateY(-179deg) scaleZ(2) translateZ(200px);
                        transform: rotateY(-179deg) scaleZ(2) translateZ(200px);
                /*issue*/
                /*transform: matrix3d(-0.999848, 0, 0.0174524, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -0.0349048, 0, -1.9997, 0, -6.98096, 0, -399.939, 1);*/
            }


            100% {
                -webkit-transform: rotateY(179deg) scaleZ(2) translateZ(200px);
                        transform: rotateY(179deg) scaleZ(2) translateZ(200px);
            }
        }

        #content1 {
            -webkit-animation: animation 2s;
                    animation: animation 2s;
            -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
                    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            /*works*/
            -webkit-transform: rotateY(-179deg) scaleZ(2) translateZ(200px);
                    transform: rotateY(-179deg) scaleZ(2) translateZ(200px);
            /*issue*/
            /*transform: matrix3d(-0.999848, 0, 0.0174524, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -0.0349048, 0, -1.9997, 0, -6.98096, 0, -399.939, 1);*/
        }
```

```html
    <div id="wrapper1" style="position:fixed; top: 100px; left:300px; perspective: 1000px; width: 250px; height:250px; border: dotted 1px blue">
        <div id="content1" style="width: 250px; height:250px; background-color:lightsalmon; opacity:0.2;">
        </div>
    </div>
```

---

The same animation with `transform` for key-frame 0% written as `matrix3D` returned from `Window.getComputedStyle()` does not make the animation work properly:

- 0% is `transform: matrix3d(-0.999848, 0, 0.0174524, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -0.0349048, 0, -1.9997, 0, -6.98096, 0, -399.939, 1);`
- 100% is `transform: rotateY(179deg) scaleZ(2) translateZ(200px);`

```js
        console.clear();
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            let content1 = document.querySelector('#content1');
            var computedTransform = window.getComputedStyle(content1).transform;
            console.log(computedTransform);

        });
```

```css
 @-webkit-keyframes animation {
            0% {
                /*works*/
                /*transform: rotateY(-179deg) scaleZ(2) translateZ(200px);*/
                /*issue*/
                -webkit-transform: matrix3d(-0.999848, 0, 0.0174524, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -0.0349048, 0, -1.9997, 0, -6.98096, 0, -399.939, 1);
                        transform: matrix3d(-0.999848, 0, 0.0174524, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -0.0349048, 0, -1.9997, 0, -6.98096, 0, -399.939, 1);
            }


            100% {
                -webkit-transform: rotateY(179deg) scaleZ(2) translateZ(200px);
                        transform: rotateY(179deg) scaleZ(2) translateZ(200px);
            }
        }

        @keyframes animation {
            0% {
                /*works*/
                /*transform: rotateY(-179deg) scaleZ(2) translateZ(200px);*/
                /*issue*/
                -webkit-transform: matrix3d(-0.999848, 0, 0.0174524, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -0.0349048, 0, -1.9997, 0, -6.98096, 0, -399.939, 1);
                        transform: matrix3d(-0.999848, 0, 0.0174524, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -0.0349048, 0, -1.9997, 0, -6.98096, 0, -399.939, 1);
            }


            100% {
                -webkit-transform: rotateY(179deg) scaleZ(2) translateZ(200px);
                        transform: rotateY(179deg) scaleZ(2) translateZ(200px);
            }
        }

        #content1 {
            -webkit-animation: animation 2s;
                    animation: animation 2s;
            -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
                    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            /*works*/
            /*transform: rotateY(-179deg) scaleZ(2) translateZ(200px);*/
            /*issue*/
            -webkit-transform: matrix3d(-0.999848, 0, 0.0174524, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -0.0349048, 0, -1.9997, 0, -6.98096, 0, -399.939, 1);
                    transform: matrix3d(-0.999848, 0, 0.0174524, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -0.0349048, 0, -1.9997, 0, -6.98096, 0, -399.939, 1);
        }
```

```html
    <div id="wrapper1" style="position:fixed; top: 100px; left:300px; perspective: 1000px; width: 250px; height:250px; border: dotted 1px blue">
        <div id="content1" style="width: 250px; height:250px; background-color:lightsalmon; opacity:0.2;">
        </div>
    </div>
```

For technical reasons I need to use as key-frame 0% a value for `transformation` properly returned from a computed style in the DOM, using `Window.getComputedStyle()` or another function if available.

My questions:

1. Is my code for the second example buggy?
2. Could you suggest an alternative way to get the computed value from the DOM?
3. Do you know of any bugs related to value returned from `Window.getComputedStyle()`?
4. Do you know of any bugs with CSS Animations and different "notation" for `transform`?

Notes: I see this issue on latest Chrome (55.0.2883.87 m) and FireFox (50.1.0).

Any solutions or ideas is welcome.

---

EDIT:

I have created few new examples (for Chrome) for further investigation.

Basically the two example rotate

`from rotateY(20deg)
 to   rotateY(90deg)`

Using transform with one type of "notation", works as expected

Desired effect
https://jsbin.com/bodaxefake/edit?html,output

When the values are instead taken by a computed CSS style and reapplied to the animation using matrix3d, the animation has a slight distortion.

Instead I would expect to reproduce the animation which exactly the same result, as for my understanding the matrix3d from `Window.getComputedStyle()` should return the same value.

Incorrect effect
https://jsbin.com/luhikahexi/edit?html,output

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is point number 4. But it isn't really a bug, it 's a complex algorithm trying to figure out what do you **want** to do.

When you make an animation move from rotate(0deg) to rotate(360deg), have you ever wondered that the 2 matrices are just the same ? If only the initial an final states are specified, the animation would not exist.

When you set the animation the way you did, the algorithm is clueless about what to do, and so the behaviour is not what you expect.  But I wouldn't say this is a bug.

I have set an animation that does what you want. The trick is to leave the matrix constant, add an initial rotation that is what we will change, and just add another rotation opposite to this one to keep the original state.

Since this snippet is a little bit extense, I have removed webkit prefixes. (on the other hand, nor really needed nowadays)

```js
console.clear();
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let content1 = document.querySelector('#content1');
  var computedTransform = window.getComputedStyle(content1).transform;
  console.log(computedTransform);

});
```

```css
@keyframes animation {
  0% {
    transform: matrix3d(-0.999848, 0, 0.0174524, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -0.0349048, 0, -1.9997, 0, -6.98096, 0, -399.939, 1);
  }
    0.1% {
    transform: rotateY(-179deg) rotateY(179deg) matrix3d(-0.999848, 0, 0.0174524, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -0.0349048, 0, -1.9997, 0, -6.98096, 0, -399.939, 1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(179deg) rotateY(179deg) matrix3d(-0.999848, 0, 0.0174524, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -0.0349048, 0, -1.9997, 0, -6.98096, 0, -399.939, 1);
  }
}
#content1 {
  animation: animation 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transform: matrix3d(-0.999848, 0, 0.0174524, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -0.0349048, 0, -1.9997, 0, -6.98096, 0, -399.939, 1);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper1" style="position:fixed; top: 100px; left:300px; perspective: 1000px; width: 250px; height:250px; border: dotted 1px blue">
  <div id="content1" style="width: 250px; height:250px; background-color:lightsalmon; opacity:0.2;">
  </div>
</div>
```

The real problem is that there is not enough information in the beginning and end point of an animation to reconstruct it. The matrices of the transforms don't have the information that you are giving in a series of individual transforms

See the snippet (in 2D): the begin and end states are the same, the animation isn't. In 3D, there are even more posibilities

```css
.test {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
  left: 100px;
}
#one {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  transform: translateX(200px);
  animation: tr1 6s infinite;
}
@keyframes tr1 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(200px)
  }
  33%,
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(200px)
  }
}
#two {
  background-color: lightblue;
  transform: translate(200px, 0px);
  animation: tr2 6s infinite;
}
@keyframes tr2 {
  0%, 33% {
    transform: translate(200px, 0px) rotate(0deg)
  }
  66%,
  100% {
    transform: translate(0px, -200px) rotate(-90deg)
  }
}
#three {
  background-color: tomato;
  transform: translate(200px, -200px) rotate(0deg) translateY(200px);
  animation: tr3 6s infinite;
}
@keyframes tr3 {
  0%, 66% {
    transform: translate(200px, -200px) rotate(0deg) translateY(200px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform:  translate(200px, -200px) rotate(-270deg)  translateY(200px) rotate(180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test" id="one">1</div>
<div class="test" id="two">2</div>
<div class="test" id="three">3</div>
```

Comment: Regarding point 3. I need a solution where in keyframe 0% is returned only by a computed dom style, do you think it is possible to achieve this? Thanks for your time on this issue.

Comment: The differences that you see for 360deg are irrelevant (e-16). It's just a rounding error when converting from deg to rad, I believe. About the other issue, I will try, but notice that you can still get the value from the DOM and just prepended the two rotations.

Comment: I have set a little trick to get the 0% to the computed value, not sure if the is ok for you

Comment: thanks for your comment, please look at my latest EDIT in my question. Any feedback is welcome :)

Comment: Now that I understand clearly your question, I'm sorry, but there is no way to get what you want. I have added an example to illustrate the point. It's not a software problem, but a mathematical one ...

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to specification https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/

As start and end keyframes are not described both as transform functions,
numerical interpolation between transform functions is not possible and browser needs instead to use matrix interpolation, (as described on the last rule of Interpolation of Transforms https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#interpolation-of-transforms),.

During matrix interpolation some information about the number of turns are lost and the animation could have a different behavior from what is expected.

Demonstration using Web Animation API (latest Chrome):
- For Keyframe Start set rotateZ to 0.
- For Keyframe Start set rotateZ to 360 or 350.
- Click button Animate.

The animation loses the turns information.

It is worthy to note that this behavior happens also if start and end keyframes are described both as transform functions but they order or number of arguments is different.

```js
 (function () {
            let data = {
                translateX: {
                    type: 'range',
                    unit: 'px',
                    min: -200,
                    max: 200,
                    steps: 400,
                    value: {
                        start: 0,
                        end: 0
                    }
                },
                translateY: {
                    type: 'range',
                    unit: 'px',
                    min: -200,
                    max: 200,
                    steps: 400,
                    value: {
                        start: 0,
                        end: 0
                    }
                },
                translateZ: {
                    type: 'range',
                    unit: 'px',
                    min: -200,
                    max: 200,
                    steps: 400,
                    value: {
                        start: 0,
                        end: 0
                    }
                },
                scaleX: {
                    type: 'range',
                    unit: '',
                    min: -3,
                    max: 3,
                    steps: 6,
                    value: {
                        start: 1,
                        end: 1
                    }
                },
                scaleY: {
                    type: 'range',
                    unit: '',
                    min: -3,
                    max: 3,
                    steps: 6,
                    value: {
                        start: 1,
                        end: 1
                    }
                },
                scaleZ: {
                    type: 'range',
                    unit: '',
                    min: -3,
                    max: 3,
                    steps: 6,
                    value: {
                        start: 1,
                        end: 1
                    }
                },
                rotateX: {
                    type: 'range',
                    unit: 'deg',
                    min: -180,
                    max: 180,
                    steps: 360,
                    value: {
                        start: 0,
                        end: 0
                    }
                },
                rotateY: {
                    type: 'range',
                    unit: 'deg',
                    min: -180,
                    max: 180,
                    steps: 360,
                    value: {
                        start: 0,
                        end: 0
                    }
                },
                rotateZ: {
                    type: 'range',
                    unit: 'deg',
                    min: 0,
                    max: 360,
                    steps: 360,
                    value: {
                        start: 0,
                        end: 0
                    }
                },
                skewX: {
                    type: 'range',
                    unit: 'deg',
                    min: 0,
                    max: 180,
                    steps: 180,
                    value: {
                        start: 0,
                        end: 0
                    }
                },
                skewY: {
                    type: 'range',
                    unit: 'deg',
                    min: 0,
                    max: 180,
                    steps: 180,
                    value: {
                        start: 0,
                        end: 0
                    }
                },
                perspective: {
                    type: 'range',
                    unit: 'px',
                    min: 200,
                    max: 1000,
                    steps: 800,
                    value: {
                        start: 1000,
                        end: 1000
                    }
                },
                perspectiveOrigin: {

                    type: 'text',
                    unit: '',
                    value: {
                        start: '50% 50%',
                        end: '50% 50%'
                    }
                }
            };

            let player;

            let submitedBy;

            let elmForm,
                elmPanelStart,
                elmPanelEnd,
                elmWrapper,
                elmContent,
                elmButtonAnimate,
                elmButtonReset;

            let getDoms = () => {
                elmForm = document.querySelector('#form');
                elmPanelStart = document.querySelector('#panel-start');
                elmPanelEnd = document.querySelector('#panel-end');
                elmWrapper = document.querySelector('#wrapper');
                elmContent = document.querySelector('#content');
                elmButtonAnimate = document.querySelector('#button-animate');
                elmButtonReset = document.querySelector('#button-reset');
            };

            let init = () => {
                getDoms();
                createUi('start');
                createUi('end');
                createUiHandlers('start');
                createUiHandlers('end');
                createUiHandlersControls();
            };

            let createUi = (type) => {
                let html = '';
                Object.keys(data).forEach((name) => {
                    let props = data[name];
                    if (props.type === 'range') {
                        html += `<label>${name}<input id="${name}-${type}" type="${props.type}" value="${props.value[type]}" name="${name}" min="${props.min}" max="${props.max}" steps="${props.steps}" ><input id="${name}-${type}-display" type="text" value="${props.value[type]}" name="${name}-${type}-show" readonly><br></label>`;
                    }
                    if (props.type === 'text') {
                        html += `<label>${name}<input id="${name}-${type}" type="${props.type}" value="${props.value[type]}" name="${name}" ></label><br>`;
                    }
                });
                if (type === 'start') {
                    elmPanelStart.innerHTML = html;
                }
                if (type === 'end') {
                    elmPanelEnd.innerHTML = html;
                }
            };

            let updateDisplay = (type, name, value) => {
                if (name === 'perspectiveOrigin') {
                    return;
                }
                let elmDisplay = document.querySelector(`#${name}-${type}-display`);
                elmDisplay.value = value;
            };

            let handler = (type, event) => {
                let name = event.target.name,
                    value = event.target.value;
                updateDisplay(type, name, value);
                updateData(type, name, value); // update data
                updateDomTarget();
            };
            let updateDomTarget = () => {
                let inline = '';
                Object.keys(data).forEach((name) => {
                    if (name === 'perspective' || name === 'perspectiveOrigin') {
                        return;
                    }
                    let props = data[name];
                    inline += ` ${name}(${props.value.start}${props.unit})`;
                });
                inline = inline.trim();
                elmContent.style.transform = inline;

                elmWrapper.style.perspective = `${data.perspective.value.start}${data.perspective.unit}`;
                elmWrapper.style.perspectiveOrigin = `${data.perspectiveOrigin.value.start}${data.perspectiveOrigin.unit}`;
            };

            let updateData = (type, name, value) => {
                data[name].value[type] = value;
            };

            let refresh = () => {
                location.reload();
            };

            let resetPlayer = () => {
                if (player) {
                    player.cancel();
                    player = null;
                }
            };

            let logicAnimate = () => {
                resetPlayer();
                let timing = {
                    duration: 1000,
                    fill: 'forwards'
                },
                kfStart = '',
                kfEnd = '';
                Object.keys(data).forEach((name) => {
                    if (name === 'perspective' || name === 'perspectiveOrigin') {
                        return;
                    }
                    let props = data[name];
                    kfStart += ` ${name}(${props.value.start}${props.unit})`;
                    kfEnd += ` ${name}(${props.value.end}${props.unit})`;
                });
                kfStart = kfStart.trim();
                kfEnd = kfEnd.trim();
                // change here
                kfStartComputedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(elmContent).transform;
                console.log(kfStartComputedStyle);
                kfStart = {
                    transform: kfStartComputedStyle
                };
                kfEnd = {
                    transform: kfEnd
                };
                elmContent.animate([kfStart, kfEnd], timing);

            };

            let createUiHandlers = (type) => {
                Object.keys(data).forEach((name) => {
                    let elm = document.querySelector(`#${name}-${type}`);
                    elm.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
                        handler(type, event);
                    });
                });
            };

            let createUiHandlersControls = (type) => {
                elmButtonAnimate.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
                    logicAnimate();
                });

                elmButtonReset.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
                    refresh();
                });
            };
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
                init();
            });
        })();
```

```css
 h1 {
            font-size: 15px;
        }

        #content {
            width: 150px;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: red;
        }

        #panel-start-wrapper {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            margin: 10px;
        }

        #panel-end-wrapper {
            position: fixed;
            top: 420px;
            right: 0;
            margin: 10px;
        }

        #panel-controls {
            position: fixed;
            top: 850px;
            right: 0;
            margin: 10px;
        }

        label {
            display: block;
        }

        input[type=text] {
            width: 50px;
        }
```

```html
   <div id="wrapper" style="position:absolute; perspective: 500px; top:10%; left:10%;">
        <div id="content">
            Hello world!
        </div>
    </div>
    <form id="form">
        <div id="panel-start-wrapper">
            <h1>Keyframe Start</h1>
            <div id="panel-start">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="panel-end-wrapper">
            <h1>Keyframe End</h1>
            <div id="panel-end">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="panel-controls">
            <button id="button-animate" type="button">Animate</button>
            <button id="button-reset" type="button">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: I would like to thanks @vals for point me out in the right direction (+1).